# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} p(n) = 1-\frac{1}{e}$

Tags: probability, constants

Let $p(n)$ denote the probability that a randomly chosen one-to-one function $f:\lbrace 1,2,3...,n \rbrace \rightarrow \lbrace 1,2,3...,n \rbrace$ has a least one  fixed point. (least one integer $k$ for which $f(k)=k, 1\leq k \leq n$)

Prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} p(n) = 1-\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: Perhaps you could let $q(n)=1-p(n)$ and then prove  $\displaystyle q(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^i}{i!}$